# error in sql plus in executing large string header

Tags: shell, unix, oracle12c, clob

I am getting this error in sql plus after executing this script . This is header of a file with >150 columns.I tried other options like

```
rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e, x || '|')).extract ('//text()'), '|')
```

but no luck.

SP2-0027: Input is too long (> 2499 characters) - line ignored

```
abc.sh
    sqlplus -s /nolog << EOF
    connect abc/pwd@orcl;
    whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
    set wrap ON
    set trimout ON
    set trimspool on
    set serveroutput on
    set pagesize 0
    set long 20000000
    set longchunksize 20000000
    set linesize 4000
    spool abc.sql
    select TO_CLOB('SCSTSUMID|IMAILSUMID|FTOMERSUMKY|FGHERNAME|EILSUMADDR|FSTSUMNM|MIHZDLESUMNM|LZSTSUMNM|PRIMSUMADDR|SECSUMADDR|CITY|STATE|POSTALSUMCD|ISOSUMCODE|UNIVSUMDCOM|UNIVSUMDCOMSUMALWSUM13T17|UNIVSUMDCOMSUMALWSUMCAN|UNIVSUMDCOMSUMALWSUMCANSUM13T17|UNIVSUMPRTR|UNIVSUMPRTRSUMALWSUM13T17|UNIVSUMPRTRSUMALWSUMCAN|UNIVSUMPRTRSUMALWSUMCANSUM13T17|UNIVSUMSHOP|UNIVSUMDCOMSUMALWSUMUKDB|UNIVSUMLIVESUMCOMBINE|UNIVSUMLIVESUMDRAFT|UNIVSUMLIVESUMKICKOFF|UNIVSUMLIVESUMISGUKSUMUKDB|UNIVSUMLIVESUMISGUKSUMNOSUMUKDB|UNIVSUMLIVESUMISGMX|UNIVSUMLIVESUMPROBOWL|UNIVSUMLIVESUMSUPERBOWL|UNIVSUMDCOMSUMRECURR|UNIVSUMDCOMSUMRECURRSUM13T17|UNIVSUMDCOMSUMALWSUMHOLDOUT|UNIVSUMDCOMSUMRCRSUMALWSUMHLDOUT|AGE|GENDER|BIRTHSUMDT|CUSTSUMRECENCYSUMDT|HISPANICSUMFLG|FAVSUMTEAMSUMCD|ACTIVESUM0SUM3MSUMFLG|ACTIVESUM4SUM6MSUMFLG|ACTIVESUM7SUM9MSUMFLG|ACTIVESUM10SUM12MSUMFLG|ACTIVESUM0SUM12MSUMFLG|ACTIVESUM13SUM15MSUMFLG|ACTIVESUM16SUM18MSUMFLG|OUTSUMMKTSUMFAVSUMTEAMSUMFLG|ORIGSUMSRC|ORIGSUMSRCSUMDT|ORIGSUMSRCSUMBU|BUSUMCLUBSSUMFLG|BUSUMDCOMSUMFLG|BUSUMLIVESUMEVENTSUMFLG|BUSUMPRTRSUMFLG|BUSUMSHOPSUMFLG|BUSUMINTLSUMFLG|BUSUMOTHRSUMFLG|BUSUMMKTGSUMFLG|CROSSOVERSUMNFLSUMCLUBSSUMFLG|LSTSUMFANTASYSUMSSN|LSTSUMSUBSUMPROD|LSTSUMSUBSUMPRODSUMSSN|LSTSUMGPDSUMSUBSUMSSN|LSTSUMGPDSUMFTSUMSSN|LSTSUMGPISUMSUBSUMSSN|LSTSUMGPISUMFTSUMSSN|LSTSUMGPISUMSUBSUMSSNSUMSSN|LSTSUMGPISUMSUBSUMSSNPLSSUMSSN|LSTSUMGPISUMSUBSUMWKLYSUMSSN|LSTSUMGPISUMSUBSUMFYTSUMSSN|LSTSUMMINIGMSUMSSN|LSTSUMMINIGMSUMSSNSUMREGSUMDT|LSTSUMTNFCHSUMSSN|LSTSUMTNFCHSUMSSNSUMREGSUMDT|LSTSUMDRAFTSUMFMPSUMSSN|LSTSUMKICKOFFSUMFMPSUMSSN|LSTSUMSBSUMFMPSUMSSN|LSTSUMPBSUMSTHSUMSSN|LSTSUMPBSUMSTBSUMSSN|SHOPSUMLSTSUMPURCHSUMDT|EMSUMLSTSUMOPENSUMDT|EMSUMLSTSUMCLICKSUMDT|WEBSUMLSTSUMVSTSUMDT|APPSUMLSTSUMVSTSUMDT|FANTASYSUMLSTSUMVSTSUMDT|LSTSUMCLUBSSUMSTHSUMSSN|LSTSUMCLUBSSUMSTBSUMSSN|DTVSUMSUNDAYSUMTICKETSUMFLG|DTVSUMSUNDAYSUMTICKETSUMACTIVESUMFLG|DTVSUMTVSUMFLG|DTVSUMTVSUMACTIVESUMFLG|DTVSUMCOMMERICALSUMFLG|DTVSUMCOMMERICALSUMACTIVESUMFLG|PARENTSUMFLG|TRANSACTIONALSUMVALUE|TSPSUMHHSUMINCOME|NICHE|GPDSUMGPIROWSUMCOUNTRY|GPESUMCOUNTRY|EMSUMNFLNSUMWEEKLYSUMFLG|EMSUMNFLNSUMWEEKLYSUMLSTSUMACTIVTYSUMDT|EMSUMNFLNSUMFLG|EMSUMNFLNSUMLSTSUMACTIVTYSUMDT|EMSUMGMFBSUMFLG|EMSUMGMFBSUMLSTSUMACTIVTYSUMDT|EMSUMTNFSUMFLG|EMSUMTNFSUMLSTSUMACTIVTYSUMDT|EMSUMGDPSUMFLG|EMSUMGDPSUMLSTSUMACTIVITYSUMDT|EMSUMFANTSUMRPTSUMFLG|EMSUMFANTSUMRPTSUMLSTSUMACTIVITYSUMDT|EMSUMFANTSUMCORESUMFLG|EMSUMFANTSUMCORESUMLSTSUMACTIVITYSUMDT|LSTSUMFANTSUMLMSUMSSN|LSTSUMFANTSUMUESUMSSN|LSTSUMFANTSUMCUSTOMSUMSSN|LSTSUMFANTSUMMANAGEDSUMSSN|SHOPSUMYOUTHSUMGIRLSSUMFLG|SHOPSUMYOUTHSUMFLG|PARENTSUMACQUISITIONSUMFLG|YOUTHSUMACQUISITIONSUMFLG|CHILDRENSUMFLG|LSTSUMPTPSUMSSN|NEWSUMTOSUMFCMSUM0SUM3MSUMFLG|FOOTBALLSUMAFFINITYSUMFLG|GPDSUMPAGEVISITSUMFLG|GPDSUMPAGEVISITSUMLSTSUMACTIVITYSUMDT|FANTSUMPAGEVISITSUMFLG|FANTSUMPAGEVISITSUMLSTSUMACTIVITYSUMDT|NFLNSUMAAMSUMSEGMENTSUMFLG|CURRSUMSSNSUMVIDEOSUMVIEWSSUMFLG|GPDSUMSTATUS|GPISUMSTATUS|GPESUMSTATUS|MXSUMOPTSUMINSUMFLAG|DESUMOPTSUMINSUMFLAG|CASUMOPTSUMINSUMFLAG|UKSUMOPTSUMINSUMFLAG|CLUSTERSUMN|CLUSTERSUMPNL|LSTSUMPBSUMFMPSUMSSN|EXTRACTSUMSEQ|HASDKSUMPROBS|SBSPNDSUMPROBS|DRAFTEDSUMFLG|EMAILSUMTIER|TSPSUMZIPSUMCD|TSPSUMSTATESUMABBREVIATION|TSPSUMADDRSUMTYPE|TSPSUMADVSUMHMSUMOWNR|TSPSUMADVSUMHHSUMSIZE|TSPSUMADVSUMHHSUMSIZESUMINDICATOR|TSPSUMADVSUMHHSUMMARITALSUMSTATUS|TSPSUMADVSUMHHSUMMARITALSUMSTATSUMIND|TSPSUMADVSUMDWELLINGSUMTYPE|TSPSUMADVSUMDWELLINGSUMTYPESUMIND|TSPSUMADVSUMTARGETSUMINCOMESUM2|TSPSUMADVSUMTARGETSUMINCOMESUMINDSUM2|TSPSUMADVSUMHHSUMEDUCATION|TSPSUMADVSUMHHSUMEDUCATIONSUMINDICATOR|TSPSUMAGESUMUNK|TSPSUMAGESUM75SUMPLUS|TSPSUMAGESUM65SUM74|TSPSUMAGESUM55SUM64|TSPSUMAGESUM45SUM54|TSPSUMAGESUM35SUM44|TSPSUMAGESUM25SUM34|TSPSUMAGESUM18SUM24|TSPSUMCHILDRENSUMAGESUM0SUM2|TSPSUMCHILDRENSUMAGESUM3SUM5|TSPSUMCHILDRENSUMAGESUM6SUM10|TSPSUMCHILDRENSUMAGESUM11SUM15|TSPSUMCHILDRENSUMAGESUM16SUM17|TSPSUMHHSUMTYPESUMFAMILYSUMCOMP|TSPSUMOCCUPATION|TSPSUMGENDERSUMPRSN|TSPSUMETHNICSUMGRP|TSPSUMETHNICSUMGRPSUMPRSN|TSPSUMLANGUAGESUMPRSN|TSPSUMTARGETSUMVALUESCORESUM2|TSPSUMCCSUMAMERSUMEXPRESS|TSPSUMCCSUMANYSUMCC|TSPSUMCCSUMBANKSUMCARD|TSPSUMCCSUMCATALOGSUMSHOWROOM|TSPSUMCCSUMCOMPUTERSUMELECTRONIC|TSPSUMCCSUMDEBITSUMCARD|TSPSUMCCSUMFINANCESUMCOSUMCARD|TSPSUMCCSUMFURNITURE|TSPSUMCCSUMGROCERY|TSPSUMCCSUMHMSUMIMPROVEMENT|TSPSUMCCSUMHMSUMOFFICESUMSUPPLY|TSPSUMCCSUMLOWSUMENDSUMDEPTSUMSTORE|TSPSUMCCSUMMAINSUMSTREETSUMRETAIL|TSPSUMCCSUMMASTERCARD|TSPSUMCCSUMMBRSHPSUMWHS|TSPSUMCCSUMMISC|TSPSUMCCSUMOILSUMGASSUMCARD|TSPSUMCCSUMSPECIALTYSUMAPPAREL|TSPSUMCCSUMSPORTINGSUMGOODS|TSPSUMCCSUMSTANDARDSUMRETAIL|TSPSUMCCSUMSTANDARDSUMSPECIALTYSUMCARD|TSPSUMCCSUMTRAVELSUMENTERTAINMENT|TSPSUMCCSUMTVSUMMAILSUMORDER|')||'TSPSUMCCSUMUPSCALESUMRETAIL|TSPSUMCCSUMUPSCALESUMSPECSUMRETAIL|TSPSUMCCSUMVISA|TSPSUMMTSUMFOOTBALLSUMENTHUSIASTS|TSPSUMMTSUMSMARTSUMPHONESUMUSER|TSPSUMMTSUMHIGHENDSUMAMSUMRANKSUMTM2|FANTSUMOPPSUMTEAMSUMNMSUMTM2|FANTSUMOPPSUMTEAMSUMRANKSUMTM2|FANTSUMLEAGUESUMIDSUMTM3|FANTSUMTEAMSUMIDSUMTM3|FANTSUMTEAMSUMNMSUMTM3|FANTSUMTEAMSUMRANKSUMTM3|FANTSUMOPPSUMTEAMSUMNMSUMTM3|FANTSUMOPPSUMTEAMSUMRANKSUMTM3|JEBBITSUMATTRIB13SUMFLG|JEBBITSUMATTRIB12SUMFANTSUMFLG|JEBBITSUMATTRIB11SUMKIDSSUMFLG|MSSUMONSUMLOCATION|MSSUMBARCLAY|BARCLAYSUMPASSIONSUMJETSETSUMIND|BARCLAYSUMPASSIONSUMELECSUMIND|BARCLAYSUMPASSIONSUMEGOERSUMIND|LSTSUMGPDSUMSTREAMSUMDT|GPDSUMMINSUMWATCHEDSUMCURRSUMSSN|GPDSUMMINSUMWATCHEDSUMPREV1SUMSSN|GPDSUMMINSUMWATCHEDSUMPREV2SUMSSN|FAVSUMTEAMSUMCDSUMIMPLIED|FAVSUMTEAMSUMCDSUMSUPPLIED|EXTRACTSUMDT' x from dual ;
    spool off;
    exit;
    EOF
```

any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting a physical limit on the length of a line of SQL in SQL*Plus. See this posting for more information on how to resolve: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4789399600346029472

Basically you're going to have to break up your input text with line breaks and concatenate the individual lines, like this:

```
abc.sh
    sqlplus -s /nolog << EOF
    connect abc/pwd@orcl;
    whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
    set wrap ON
    set trimout ON
    set trimspool on
    set serveroutput on
    set pagesize 0
    set long 20000000
    set longchunksize 20000000
    set linesize 4000
    spool abc.sql
    select TO_CLOB('SCSTSUMID|IMAILSUMID|FTOMERSUMKY|FGHERNAME|EILSUMADDR|FSTSUMNM|MIHZDLESUMNM|LZSTSUMNM|PRIMSUMADDR|SECSUMADDR|CITY|STATE|POSTALSUMCD|ISOSUMCODE|UNIVSUMDCOM|UNIVSUMDCOMSUMALWSUM13T17|UNIVSUMDCOMSUMALWSUMCAN|UNIVSUMDCOMSUMALWSUMCANSUM13T17|UNIVSUMPRTR|UNIVSUMPRTRSUMALWSUM13T17|UNIVSUMPRTRSUMALWSUMCAN|UNIVSUMPRTRSUMALWSUMCANSUM13T17|UNIVSUMSHOP|UNIVSUMDCOMSUMALWSUMUKDB|UNIVSUMLIVESUMCOMBINE|UNIVSUMLIVESUMDRAFT|UNIVSUMLIVESUMKICKOFF|UNIVSUMLIVESUMISGUKSUMUKDB|'
    || 'UNIVSUMLIVESUMISGUKSUMNOSUMUKDB|UNIVSUMLIVESUMISGMX|UNIVSUMLIVESUMPROBOWL|UNIVSUMLIVESUMSUPERBOWL|UNIVSUMDCOMSUMRECURR|UNIVSUMDCOMSUMRECURRSUM13T17|UNIVSUMDCOMSUMALWSUMHOLDOUT|UNIVSUMDCOMSUMRCRSUMALWSUMHLDOUT|AGE|GENDER|BIRTHSUMDT|CUSTSUMRECENCYSUMDT|HISPANICSUMFLG|FAVSUMTEAMSUMCD|ACTIVESUM0SUM3MSUMFLG|ACTIVESUM4SUM6MSUMFLG|ACTIVESUM7SUM9MSUMFLG|ACTIVESUM10SUM12MSUMFLG|ACTIVESUM0SUM12MSUMFLG|ACTIVESUM13SUM15MSUMFLG|ACTIVESUM16SUM18MSUMFLG|OUTSUMMKTSUMFAVSUMTEAMSUMFLG|ORIGSUMSRC|ORIGSUMSRCSUMDT|'
    || 'ORIGSUMSRCSUMBU|BUSUMCLUBSSUMFLG|BUSUMDCOMSUMFLG|BUSUMLIVESUMEVENTSUMFLG|BUSUMPRTRSUMFLG|BUSUMSHOPSUMFLG|BUSUMINTLSUMFLG|BUSUMOTHRSUMFLG|BUSUMMKTGSUMFLG|CROSSOVERSUMNFLSUMCLUBSSUMFLG|LSTSUMFANTASYSUMSSN|LSTSUMSUBSUMPROD|LSTSUMSUBSUMPRODSUMSSN|LSTSUMGPDSUMSUBSUMSSN|LSTSUMGPDSUMFTSUMSSN|LSTSUMGPISUMSUBSUMSSN|LSTSUMGPISUMFTSUMSSN|LSTSUMGPISUMSUBSUMSSNSUMSSN|LSTSUMGPISUMSUBSUMSSNPLSSUMSSN|LSTSUMGPISUMSUBSUMWKLYSUMSSN|LSTSUMGPISUMSUBSUMFYTSUMSSN|LSTSUMMINIGMSUMSSN|LSTSUMMINIGMSUMSSNSUMREGSUMDT|'
    || 'LSTSUMTNFCHSUMSSN|LSTSUMTNFCHSUMSSNSUMREGSUMDT|LSTSUMDRAFTSUMFMPSUMSSN|LSTSUMKICKOFFSUMFMPSUMSSN|LSTSUMSBSUMFMPSUMSSN|LSTSUMPBSUMSTHSUMSSN|LSTSUMPBSUMSTBSUMSSN|SHOPSUMLSTSUMPURCHSUMDT|EMSUMLSTSUMOPENSUMDT|EMSUMLSTSUMCLICKSUMDT|WEBSUMLSTSUMVSTSUMDT|APPSUMLSTSUMVSTSUMDT|FANTASYSUMLSTSUMVSTSUMDT|LSTSUMCLUBSSUMSTHSUMSSN|LSTSUMCLUBSSUMSTBSUMSSN|DTVSUMSUNDAYSUMTICKETSUMFLG|DTVSUMSUNDAYSUMTICKETSUMACTIVESUMFLG|DTVSUMTVSUMFLG|DTVSUMTVSUMACTIVESUMFLG|DTVSUMCOMMERICALSUMFLG|'
    || 'DTVSUMCOMMERICALSUMACTIVESUMFLG|PARENTSUMFLG|TRANSACTIONALSUMVALUE|TSPSUMHHSUMINCOME|NICHE|GPDSUMGPIROWSUMCOUNTRY|GPESUMCOUNTRY|EMSUMNFLNSUMWEEKLYSUMFLG|EMSUMNFLNSUMWEEKLYSUMLSTSUMACTIVTYSUMDT|EMSUMNFLNSUMFLG|EMSUMNFLNSUMLSTSUMACTIVTYSUMDT|EMSUMGMFBSUMFLG|EMSUMGMFBSUMLSTSUMACTIVTYSUMDT|EMSUMTNFSUMFLG|EMSUMTNFSUMLSTSUMACTIVTYSUMDT|EMSUMGDPSUMFLG|EMSUMGDPSUMLSTSUMACTIVITYSUMDT|EMSUMFANTSUMRPTSUMFLG|EMSUMFANTSUMRPTSUMLSTSUMACTIVITYSUMDT|EMSUMFANTSUMCORESUMFLG|EMSUMFANTSUMCORESUMLSTSUMACTIVITYSUMDT|'
    || 'LSTSUMFANTSUMLMSUMSSN|LSTSUMFANTSUMUESUMSSN|LSTSUMFANTSUMCUSTOMSUMSSN|LSTSUMFANTSUMMANAGEDSUMSSN|SHOPSUMYOUTHSUMGIRLSSUMFLG|SHOPSUMYOUTHSUMFLG|PARENTSUMACQUISITIONSUMFLG|YOUTHSUMACQUISITIONSUMFLG|CHILDRENSUMFLG|LSTSUMPTPSUMSSN|NEWSUMTOSUMFCMSUM0SUM3MSUMFLG|FOOTBALLSUMAFFINITYSUMFLG|GPDSUMPAGEVISITSUMFLG|GPDSUMPAGEVISITSUMLSTSUMACTIVITYSUMDT|FANTSUMPAGEVISITSUMFLG|FANTSUMPAGEVISITSUMLSTSUMACTIVITYSUMDT|NFLNSUMAAMSUMSEGMENTSUMFLG|CURRSUMSSNSUMVIDEOSUMVIEWSSUMFLG|'
    || 'GPDSUMSTATUS|GPISUMSTATUS|GPESUMSTATUS|MXSUMOPTSUMINSUMFLAG|DESUMOPTSUMINSUMFLAG|CASUMOPTSUMINSUMFLAG|UKSUMOPTSUMINSUMFLAG|CLUSTERSUMN|CLUSTERSUMPNL|LSTSUMPBSUMFMPSUMSSN|EXTRACTSUMSEQ|HASDKSUMPROBS|SBSPNDSUMPROBS|DRAFTEDSUMFLG|EMAILSUMTIER|TSPSUMZIPSUMCD|TSPSUMSTATESUMABBREVIATION|TSPSUMADDRSUMTYPE|TSPSUMADVSUMHMSUMOWNR|TSPSUMADVSUMHHSUMSIZE|TSPSUMADVSUMHHSUMSIZESUMINDICATOR|TSPSUMADVSUMHHSUMMARITALSUMSTATUS|TSPSUMADVSUMHHSUMMARITALSUMSTATSUMIND|TSPSUMADVSUMDWELLINGSUMTYPE|'
    || 'TSPSUMADVSUMDWELLINGSUMTYPESUMIND|TSPSUMADVSUMTARGETSUMINCOMESUM2|TSPSUMADVSUMTARGETSUMINCOMESUMINDSUM2|TSPSUMADVSUMHHSUMEDUCATION|TSPSUMADVSUMHHSUMEDUCATIONSUMINDICATOR|TSPSUMAGESUMUNK|TSPSUMAGESUM75SUMPLUS|TSPSUMAGESUM65SUM74|TSPSUMAGESUM55SUM64|TSPSUMAGESUM45SUM54|TSPSUMAGESUM35SUM44|TSPSUMAGESUM25SUM34|TSPSUMAGESUM18SUM24|TSPSUMCHILDRENSUMAGESUM0SUM2|TSPSUMCHILDRENSUMAGESUM3SUM5|TSPSUMCHILDRENSUMAGESUM6SUM10|TSPSUMCHILDRENSUMAGESUM11SUM15|TSPSUMCHILDRENSUMAGESUM16SUM17|'
    || 'TSPSUMHHSUMTYPESUMFAMILYSUMCOMP|TSPSUMOCCUPATION|TSPSUMGENDERSUMPRSN|TSPSUMETHNICSUMGRP|TSPSUMETHNICSUMGRPSUMPRSN|TSPSUMLANGUAGESUMPRSN|TSPSUMTARGETSUMVALUESCORESUM2|TSPSUMCCSUMAMERSUMEXPRESS|TSPSUMCCSUMANYSUMCC|TSPSUMCCSUMBANKSUMCARD|TSPSUMCCSUMCATALOGSUMSHOWROOM|TSPSUMCCSUMCOMPUTERSUMELECTRONIC|TSPSUMCCSUMDEBITSUMCARD|TSPSUMCCSUMFINANCESUMCOSUMCARD|TSPSUMCCSUMFURNITURE|TSPSUMCCSUMGROCERY|TSPSUMCCSUMHMSUMIMPROVEMENT|TSPSUMCCSUMHMSUMOFFICESUMSUPPLY|TSPSUMCCSUMLOWSUMENDSUMDEPTSUMSTORE|'
    || 'TSPSUMCCSUMMAINSUMSTREETSUMRETAIL|TSPSUMCCSUMMASTERCARD|TSPSUMCCSUMMBRSHPSUMWHS|TSPSUMCCSUMMISC|TSPSUMCCSUMOILSUMGASSUMCARD|TSPSUMCCSUMSPECIALTYSUMAPPAREL|TSPSUMCCSUMSPORTINGSUMGOODS|TSPSUMCCSUMSTANDARDSUMRETAIL|TSPSUMCCSUMSTANDARDSUMSPECIALTYSUMCARD|TSPSUMCCSUMTRAVELSUMENTERTAINMENT|TSPSUMCCSUMTVSUMMAILSUMORDER|')||'TSPSUMCCSUMUPSCALESUMRETAIL|TSPSUMCCSUMUPSCALESUMSPECSUMRETAIL|TSPSUMCCSUMVISA|TSPSUMMTSUMFOOTBALLSUMENTHUSIASTS|TSPSUMMTSUMSMARTSUMPHONESUMUSER|'
    || 'TSPSUMMTSUMHIGHENDSUMAMSUMRANKSUMTM2|FANTSUMOPPSUMTEAMSUMNMSUMTM2|FANTSUMOPPSUMTEAMSUMRANKSUMTM2|FANTSUMLEAGUESUMIDSUMTM3|FANTSUMTEAMSUMIDSUMTM3|FANTSUMTEAMSUMNMSUMTM3|FANTSUMTEAMSUMRANKSUMTM3|FANTSUMOPPSUMTEAMSUMNMSUMTM3|FANTSUMOPPSUMTEAMSUMRANKSUMTM3|JEBBITSUMATTRIB13SUMFLG|JEBBITSUMATTRIB12SUMFANTSUMFLG|JEBBITSUMATTRIB11SUMKIDSSUMFLG|MSSUMONSUMLOCATION|MSSUMBARCLAY|BARCLAYSUMPASSIONSUMJETSETSUMIND|BARCLAYSUMPASSIONSUMELECSUMIND|BARCLAYSUMPASSIONSUMEGOERSUMIND|LSTSUMGPDSUMSTREAMSUMDT|'
    || 'GPDSUMMINSUMWATCHEDSUMCURRSUMSSN|GPDSUMMINSUMWATCHEDSUMPREV1SUMSSN|GPDSUMMINSUMWATCHEDSUMPREV2SUMSSN|FAVSUMTEAMSUMCDSUMIMPLIED|FAVSUMTEAMSUMCDSUMSUPPLIED|EXTRACTSUMDT' x 
    from dual ;
    spool off;
    exit;
    EOF
```